# how to manage large number of requests in struts1 java web application with tomcat 6

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, tomcat6, struts1

I have a JSP page through which user generate some reports. It has a form with a submit button and when a user press the submit button the form data is passed to a struts1 action class which then fetch data from database based on the form data and creates the report using jasper-report. The problem is when a number of users try to create the report at the same time then the generated report's data get mixed up. Now how can i solve this?

Comment: Can you show your code where the data is getting mixed up? You might be running into concurrency issues (multiple requests accessing the same resource). And those are hard even if we are looking at the code.

Comment: show your code , else no one can help you